# Expose Docker Image Environment Variables to Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have a docker image that builds using docker-compose and has a provided environment file, like such:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    ...
  redis:
    image: redis:4.0
  api:
    build: ./src/api
    env_file: ./integrationtests.env
  tests_integration:
    build: ./tests/Integration
    env_file:
      - ./integrationtests.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - api
```

The environment file has a few definitions, but the one I'm most concerned about looks like this `ApiUrl=http:\\api`

I have a docker file for the integration tests defined as such:

```
FROM apline
WORKDIR /app

ENV ApiUrl $ApiUrl
COPY ./scripts ./scripts

ENTRYPOINT [ "printenv" ]
```

When I run `docker-compose up` it correctly prints out all the environment variables that are available during the build phase.  But when I do `docker run  --entrypoint printenv mycontainer` the env var `ApiUrl` is empty.

How can I make sure that specific variable is available both during build and run phases?

Answer (score 0):

Building Docker images happens fairly early in the Docker Compose process; settings like `environment:` are never visible to the code that runs in a `Dockerfile` (similarly network settings and volume mounts).

An image is supposed to be reusable across environments.  My recommendation would be to make the default value for the environment variable as generic as you can, but expect it to be overwritten.

```
FROM alpine
ENV API_URL /
CMD printenv
```

If you want to run the image with the environment and volume settings from the `docker-compose.yml` in effect, you can use [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/)

```
docker-compose run tests_integration printenv
```

If you really need the value to be hard-coded in the image, and it’s a value that would be useful in all environments for any potential user that would have a copy of the image, a [Dockerfile `ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) and the corresponding [Docker Compose `build: {args: ...}`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args) is a better match.

Answer (score 0):

try using args instead of env_file here's a good reference [link](https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-pass-environment-variables/) your docker compose file should be something like this exemple :

```
  version: '3'

    services:
      somename:
        build:
          context: ./app
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
          args:
            some_variable_name: a_value
```